# How to avoid geom_hex hexagons getting flattened

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot some hexagons with `ggplot2` in different colors.
When I try it as the code below I get squashed hexagons

```
library(ggplot2)
coords <- 
data.frame(x=c(1.11803398874989,0.559016994374948,-0.559016994374947,-1.11803398874989,-0.559016994374948,0.559016994374947,2.23606797749979,1.1180339887499,-1.11803398874989,-2.23606797749979,-1.1180339887499,1.11803398874989,1.73205080756888,1.22464679914735e-16),
           y=c(0,0.968245836551854,0.968245836551854,1.36919674566051e-16,-0.968245836551854,-0.968245836551855,0,1.93649167310371,1.93649167310371,2.73839349132101e-16,-1.93649167310371,-1.93649167310371,1,2),
           kind=c(rep("blue",12),"red","blue"))

ggplot (data = coords, aes (x = round(x,digits =13), y = round(y,digits=13), fill = kind , group = 1)) +
  geom_hex (colour = "red", stat = StatIdentity) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = 0 : 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c (0, 2)) +
  coord_equal ()
```

however when I try to plot only the first 12 hexagons I don't have any problems

```
# fine result
ggplot (data = coords[1:12,], aes (x = round(x,digits =13), y = round(y,digits=13), fill = kind , group = 1)) +
  geom_hex (colour = "red", stat = StatIdentity) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = 0 : 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c (0, 2)) +
  coord_equal ()
```

Also when I do not round the values I get an empty plot. 
What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to draw 19 hexagons that do not overlap. For that purpose I was able to draw it as the following:

```
coords <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 7),
    y = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5),
    kind=c(rep("blue",12),"red","blue","red","blue",rep("blue",3))
  )

ggplot (data = coords, aes (x = x, y = y, fill = kind , group = 1)) +
  geom_hex (colour = "red", stat = StatIdentity) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0:1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,2))
```

It seems that it is better to avoid floats.